# after creating language switcher RouteNotFoundException Route [{$name}] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes, undefined

after grouping urls with prefix in web.php
I have created language switcher like this

```
Route::redirect('/','/ge');
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}'],function (){
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
```

I tested it and it was working fine. now I need to add links ( language switcher) but after I do this I receive an exception and an error.

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [] not defined. (View: /Users/mac/laravel/Template/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)
```

```
        throw new RouteNotFoundException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");
```

my list looks like that

```
 <div class="languages">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{{route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getCurrentRoute(),'ge')}}">GE</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getCurrentRoute(),'en')}}">EN</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getCurrentRoute(),'ru')}}">RU </a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I even used \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::route()->getName() instead of route(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getCurrentRoute() but looks like problem is something different.
Route::currentRouteName() is not working as well

Comment: href="{{route(route(\Illuminate ... is this a typo? you call the route() function twice

Comment: @GertB. I made a mistake when pasting my code here. will edit post.

Comment: Try this: \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName()

Comment: @GertB. Thanks for help, I fixed error and posted solution below.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a fix here
https://spacecode.dev/post/route-route-name-not-defined-solve-the-problem
run commands

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

will fix that.